# What is the answer (or opposite side) for "Less is more"?

Tags: idioms

I mean it's not always true. Sometimes it's better to do more than less. 
Is there any opposite idiom for "less is more"? ~~~~

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "opposite"... Technically the "opposite" would be "more is less" but I **think** you mean "more is more"... which is an idiom, but not used much.

Comment: I can't think of a phrase (if I do I'll write it) but a simple: "Not in this case" reply might serve the purpose :-).

Comment: Also, please explain **your** understanding of the concept, "less is more".

Comment: Like, um, *sometimes more is more*? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to oppose the meaning of [less is more](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/226400.html) which emphasises the advantages of simplicity over (too many) details:

> The notion that simplicity and clarity lead to good design. ([The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/index.html))

you could use:

> *For want of a nail the shoe was lost*

which is the beginning of a [longer phrase](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/For+want+of+a+nail+the+shoe+was+lost%3B+for+want+of+a+shoe+the+horse+...) that implies that overlooking small details can have disastrous consequences.

If you want to say that all work is appreciated and every contribution can be useful (to oppose someone's dismissal of extra effort of work):

> [every little bit helps](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/every+little+bit+helps)

is another idiom.

To simply say that you want or it is necessary to put additional effort into something:

> to [go the extra mile](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+the+extra+mile)

as in: *we need to go the extra mile in this case* or *I like to go the extra mile* can be used.

or

> [if it/a thing is worth doing, it's worth doing well](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/if-it-a-thing-is-worth-doing-it-s-worth-doing-well)

this doesn't specifically  mention additional details or work, but this meaning might be implied.

I also agree with Catija and snailboat that "more is more" is easily understood and is the direct opposite of "less is more.

Answer (score 0):

*Less is more* referred to a minimalist design philosophy. A stock phrase that comes to mind, which means roughly the opposite and can be applied to any domain, is:

It's the Swiss Army Knife of ___________________ [insert domain here].

See [these examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20Swiss%20Army%20Knife%20of&oq=The%20Swiss%20Army%20Knife%20of&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.5539j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

If someone else said, "Less is more" and you wanted to present a rebuttal, I think the obvious phrase would be, "Sometimes. But sometimes less is just less" or "But sometimes more is more".

As a general philosophy, I think the common opposite idea is just the default. When someone presents a paradoxical statement like that, the opposite is our normal common sense, intuitive idea, which often doesn't have a name or a catch-phrase because ... because it's the normal, common sense, intuitive idea. We don't have common phrases to express the idea that heat is hot or that tall people are taller than short people or that sick people have sicknesses, because that's just what the words mean already.